# Не судите строго

Tags: c++

Подскажите,как сделать так чтобы огромной количество if-ов работало вместе и приводило к ответу? 
 Моя программа ничего не выводит, а должна

***ЕСЛИ КОМУ ИНТЕРЕСНА ЗАДАЧА***

Яша плавал в бассейне размером N×M метров и устал. В этот момент он обнаружил, что находится на расстоянии X метров от одного из длинных бортиков (не обязательно от ближайшего) и Y метров от одного из коротких бортиков. Какое минимальное расстояние должен проплыть Яша, чтобы выбраться из бассейна на бортик?

Формат входных данных
Программа получает на вход числа N, M, X, Y.
Формат выходных данных
Программа должна вывести число метров, которое нужно проплыть Яше до бортика.

**Sample Input:**

23
52
8
43

**Sample Output:**

8

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int me, m, n, bo,x,y;
        cin >> n >> m >>x>> y>> bo>>me ;
        if (n>=m) {
            bo = n;
            me = m;
        }
        else {
            me = n;
            bo = m;
        }
        if (me - y >= y) {
            y = y;
        }
        else {
            me = n - y;
        }
        if (bo - x >= x) {
            x = x;
        }
        else {
            bo = x - x;
        }
        if (x > y) {
            cout << y;
        }
        else {
            cout << x;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: для начала. а почему вы вводите 6(!) чисел а не 4 как в условии.

Comment: IF не нужны вообще. Имея сумму и одно слагаемое, найти минимальное из слагаемых - задачка вовсе плёвая.

Comment: `me = n - y;` вот тут что за фигня написана?) может `y = me - y`?

Comment: `#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 int me, m, n, bo,x,y;
 cin >> n >> m >>x>> y;
 if (n>=m) {
  bo = n;
  me = m;
 }
 else {
  me = n;
  bo = m;
 }
 if (me - x >= x) {
  x = x;
 }
 else {
  x = me - x;
 }
 if (bo - y >= y) {
  y = y;
 }
 else {
  y = bo - y;
 }
 if (x > y) {
  cout << y;
 }
 else {
  cout << x;
 }
 return 0;
}`                                         Спасибо каждому за помощь,  я разобрался в задаче! Нужно было всего лишь исправить ошибки, отмеченные выше и чуть-чуть изменить код

Comment: Вместо `if (me - y >= y) {
            y = y;
        }
        else {
            me = n - y;
        }
        if (bo - x >= x) {
            x = x;
        }
        else {
            bo = x - x;`     нужно было писать `if (me - x >= x) {
  x = x;
 }
 else {
  x = me - x;
 }
 if (bo - y >= y) {
  y = y;
 }
 else {
  y = bo - y;
 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем там вообще `if`?

```
int main() {
    int N, M, X, Y;
    cin >> N >> M >> X >> Y;
    if (N < M) swap(N,M);
    cout << min(min(X,M-X),min(Y,N-Y)) << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Можно еще короче: `cout << min({X,M-X,Y,N-Y}) << endl;`

Comment: Ваше решение, конечно, правильное, но оператор Swap я еще не проходил(обучаюсь на stepike, курс от яндекс) , да и задача составлена для того, чтобы ее решили только if-ами

Comment: @Авторитетныйинеподкупный Свап можно заменить на `int t = N; N = M; M = t;`.